# "WARNING in Duplicated path in loadChildren detected during a rebuild." paths duplicados

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-6

O que pode estar errado para acarretar no `warn`?
`WARNING in Duplicated path in loadChildren detected during a rebuild. We will take the latest version detected and override it to save rebuild time. You should perform a full build to validate that your routes don't overlap.`

Answer (score 1):

Há alguns motivos que encontrei para ocorrer o `warn`. Foi reportado na [issue 8722 do angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8722) mas encontrei uma além destas respostas que ajustaram.

- **lazyModules em angular.json**
  este foi o motivo de eu ficar alguns dias tentando ajustar este `warn`. Com o Angular 6 existe uma nova propriedade chamada *lazyModules* em `"architect":{ "build":{ "options"{ "lazyModules":[] } } }`  Nesta propriedade devem ser informados os módulos que não estão traçados em rotas e que você gostaria que fossem carregados de maneira preguiçosa. Se você informar um módulo nesta propriedade e o mesmo módulo nas rotas, vai ocorrer o `warn`. Limpando esta propriedade parou de ocorrer o `warn` para mim.
- **rotas duplicadas**
  dentro desta issue do angular-cli foi ressaltado de que o caminho do módulo pode estar duplicando a rota do cli do angular, para isso é preciso informar o caminho corretamente na rota para que o cli entenda a rota raíz e não duplique com as rotas filhas. Este `warn` foi ajustado pelos demais com o ajuste da propriedade `loadChildren` como segue:
  Antes (com erro):
  `{ path: 'orders', loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'}`
  Agora:
  `{ path: 'orders', loadChildren: 'app/orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'}`
- **última rota com uma vírgula no final**
  sim, você não leu errado kk, pelos testes que fiz aqui isso não ocorreu comigo utilizando o angular 6, porém alguns usuários arurmaram o `warn` constatados na *issue 8722* apenas acrescentando uma vírgula no final da última rota declarada.
  `{ path: 'threed', loadChildren: './threed/threed.module#ThreedModule'},`

achei também em outros sites de que se for informado um link no arquivo tsconfig.json na propriedade `"paths"` poderia informar um `loadChildren` igual para outras rotas, mas não conseguir reproduzir o `warn` fazendo isso também.
Com esta pergunta/resposta espero que demais usuários consigam resolver este `warn` de modo mais fácil. Abraço

Comment: Quem quiser saber mais sobre o link no tsconfig.json está [neste link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19397) respondida pelo usuário _moseleman_